# Why cfs_write() consumes too much ROM memory?

Tags: memory-management, out-of-memory, contiki

I am developing a Contiki application and I am running out of ROM memory. I want to use the Contiki File System (CFS) to write a small file (32 bytes long), so I add the following code:

```
 fd_write = cfs_open(filename, CFS_WRITE);
 n = cfs_write(fd_write, message, sizeof(message)); //Message size is 32 bytes
 cfs_close(fd_write);
```

The problem is that cfs_write() increases the .text section by 3210 bytes. I find about that because the code size removing cfs_write() is:

```
  text   data    bss    dec    hex filename
  23912    114   4710  28736   7040 coffee-example.sky
```

and with cfs_write() the code size is:

```
 text   data    bss    dec    hex filename
 27122    114   4710  31946   7cca coffee-example.sky
```

Notice that cfs_write() increases the .text section by 3210 bytes. Why cfs_write() increases the .text section so much? How can I reduce the size of cfs_write() in the .text section?

Best regards,

Sergio Diaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `cfs_write()` is not a huge function on its own, it does call other functions. If you use `cfs_write()` from the application code, all these other functions are also linked in the executable.

For example, if you're using the Coffee implementation of CFS (there are multiple implementations), it calls `merge_log()`, which in turn calls a bunch of functions on its own.

There is no easy way to optimize this usage, as the CFS code is already developed with the goal of producing compact binary code in mind.